# Weblogic server: Profiling JDBC calls on a DataSource from an weblogic application

Tags: jdbc, weblogic, profiler

We are running applications on weblogic server. We have a requirement in which we want to monitor jdbc calls made on a data source. We only want to collect time taken for each sql to execute and number of times a sql is fired. I also want to collect this information per user session.

There are a few utilties on the web like weblogic jdbc spy, log4jdbc, etc. But they all required additional setup on the data source and provide output on a separate logging file which does not contain per session output as such. Is it possible to create another weblogic application that listens on a given data source and record all the sql and the timings per session? Please provide any pointers that you have.

TIA,
Siva Rajesh

Answer (score 0):

Oracle JRockit Flight Recorder can be answer for you. I'm using him. Just make a record in defined time and then analyze gathered jfr file with Oracle JRockit Mission Control.

**Links:**

[Oracle JRockit Flight Recorder manual](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E15289_01/doc.40/e15070.pdf)

[Oracle JRockit Mission Control](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/jrockit/overview/index-090630.html)

Or you can find your answer with parameter -Doracle.jdbc.Trace=true -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/jdbc/demo/OracleLog.properties